Alternatives to LambdaExpression.Compile()
My WPF application (.Net 6) provides a way for users to define very simple boolean functions used to compare a variable 'x', e.g. x < 5 or x >=5 && x <= 10. During startup, these strings get compiled into delegates for use elsewhere across the application, using this code:
public Func<double, bool> CreateDelegate(string expressionText)
{
    var expressionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x");
    var lambdaExpression = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(
        new[] { expressionParameter },
        null,
        expressionText);
    return (Func<double, bool>)lambdaExpression.Compile();
}

However I've noticed that each call to DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda() is very slow (~1.2s), resulting in the app taking a long time to start up, depending on how many of these functions have been defined.
Are there any more performant alternatives for what I'm trying to do?

Do building needs to be done synchronously on the UI thread? Can you spin of a background thread that calls compile? You might even call those Compile methods in parallel.

That is an excessively long time. Are you sure about that?

I'd expected parsing to be slow depending on the string being passed. But Compile?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain apologies, after looking again it is the call to DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda() that is taking the time, averaging 1.2-1.3s for a simple expression like "x < 5".

@canton7 apologies, see my previous comment

Isn't there a way to parse and compile only if the source changed and otherwise load a precompiled version? I have a very dark memory of something like that from my olden CSscript days ...

you could save some hashcode of your code and compare if the hashcode of your current call is equal to the saved one.

Saving the resulting lambda expressions or delegates to file would be a good way of caching them, however it doesn't look immediately obvious that these types can be serialised?

That's still a ridiculously long time to parse such a simple expression. I'd work on finding the problem there, before anything else

^^ I second canton7. I used to compile several scripts in the 2 figure line numbers on every start of the software and only explored artifact caching for later use (which never came, so I just dropped it at some point). And we didn't have so bad parsing times. > 1s per line would have been insufferable.
